# Entity Framework scaffolding includes unwanted reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two projects, one contains various Azure Functions which populate a database and another is a web API which provides endpoints for that database.

The first project (functions) uses Entity Framework (EF6) code-first migrations to create the relevant tables based on the models I define.

The second project (API) uses Entity Framework Core 2.0 to scaffold the existing database back into models that can be used by MVC.

This is how I am defining the models in the functions project:

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Marketplace Marketplace { get; set; }
}

public class Marketplace
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping that scaffolding the database would create similar models, however it tries to create a reference to Invoices in the model, which in turn reference a marketplace, potentially creating an endless reference. This is the model generated by the scaffolding migration:

```
public partial class Marketplace
{
    public Marketplace()
    {
        Invoices = new HashSet<Invoice>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can tell EF Core to scaffold the Marketplace table without any references? The table should be referenced by other models, but it should not reference any itself.

Comment: When you add `Marketplace` to `Invoice`, doesn't it automatically means that it's a `1: Many relationship` i.e. 1 `Invoice` is connected to only 1 `Marketplace` but 1 `Marketplace` is connected to many `Invoices`?

Comment: Is the problem in your first or second project ? It would be kind of useful to know if code first or db first is troubling you.

Comment: The problem is with the second project, when I try to return an invoice for an API endpoint (e.g. /Invoices/{id}) and include the marketplace then it tries to return a list of invoices for that marketplace as well - which I don't want it to do. I just want the ID and name to be returned.

Comment: if you use DB first approach, and it produce extra unwanted linking between object every time you scaffold, then you have to solve the problem at DB level, or solve the problem after scaffolding and STOP scaffolding. Personally i would choose the first approach.